# Retrieve git repository name during git push at server level

Tags: git

I am new to git, so my understanding is fairly naive. In Perforce I can do `p4 describe`, and it can give me all the info I need for a changelist.

Here when I do `git push origin master`, I want to know which repository the commits are being pushed to during a pre-receive hook at the git server level.

I have seen option like basename `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, but this happens to be at the client level. I want to do something similar at the server level.

Is this possible?

Comment: In addition to the below answer, git config remote.origin.url will also give the remote url.

Answer (score 2):

`git remote -v` will tell you what remote repository(ies) your pull and push are coming from.

Example output:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:null/Python.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:null/Python.git (push)
```

The name of the repository is **null/Python**.

Also, unless I'm misunderstanding you, you are shown what repository the files are being pushed to during a push:

```
To git@github.com:null/Python.git
 * [new branch]      ruby-version -> ruby-version
```

Again, **null/Python** is the name of the remote repository.

Comment: Sure. But git remote works assuming you have [remote] info in the config file on the git server side.. What if there is none ??

Comment: If your branch isn't pushing or pulling upstream, you won't get any entries, as that information cannot exist.

Comment: I am doing a "git push origin master". On the pre-receive hook I am doing a "git remove -v", but as I said it works if and only if there is [remote] info in the config file for the repo on the git server and not the client

Comment: Is your local branch set to push upstream?  Do you get a failure if you push?

Comment: yes I can push upstream and in general I dont get any failure if I dont use the command. Its the command that fails during the pre-receive hook!!